# Are questions that are related to raspberry pi in scope of devops?

Tags: support

Are questions that are related to raspberry pi like [this one](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/2434/210) in scope of the devops stackexchange site?

Comment: A tricky one :D   Let's see what the community has to say.  I wouldn't mind Raspberry Pi qns unless and until it is DevOps related. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question specifically involves both development, operations and Raspberry Pis, I don't see why not. I don't think that question is appropriate because it's very generic and could just as well be an operations task or home automation.